# Definition of Index Set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The most widely used Index Sets are $\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{R}$. Both of which are totally-ordered-set.

Is it important for Index-Sets to be totally ordered set?

Comment: No; and "indexed family" of sets $\{ A_i \}$ where $A_i \in \mathcal A$ is a function from a set $I$. $f: I \to \mathcal A$, where we define $A_i=f(i)$.

Comment: Index sets don't have to be totally or even partially ordered, and although the symbols $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb R$ have commonly agreed upon total orderings, there is no necessity for those orders to be included when using these symbols. Indeed, if we were discussing something topological, we'd be considering $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb R$ as topological spaces, and if we were discussing something about topological groups $\ldots$

Comment: It is a natural generalization of succession $\{ a_n \}$, where $a_n \in A$. $f: \mathbb N \to A$ where $a_n=f(n)$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: I think you mean "sequence", right?

Answer (score 1):

Do not confuse index set with an index**ed** set. The sets N and R are simple sets, you can define a total-order upon their elements, but even if you do, they are not yet index sets. Indexed sets are build when you define a function between a totally-ordered set (as the domain) and an arbitrary set (in the codomain), then, the totally-ordered set you used becomes the index set, because you used it to index the arbitrary set. Does that makes sense?

To your question: Is it important for Index-Sets to be totally ordered set?

You can define a function between a set with another, but there would be no ordered define, so, consider the set {1, 2}, it is no different than the set {2,1}, the only way you can tell the element 1 goes "first", and then the element 2 is because we have defined a total-order in the set {1,2}.

So, I would say, no, is not important that index-sets are totally ordered sets, it simply makes the indexation meaningful.